# Hide specific elements from html using css

Tags: html, css

I've an html file and need to hide some elements from this.
My code is look like this,

```
<div class="test">
   <a href="#" class="demo">Demo1</a>
</div>
<div class="test">
   <a href="#" class="demo">Demo2</a>
</div>
<div class="test">
   <a href="#" class="demo">Demo3</a>
</div>
<div class="test">
   <a href="#" class="demo">Demo4</a>
</div>
```

I want to hide the Demo2 and Demo4 links using css. Kindly help me to do this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type):

> The `:nth-of-type` CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has an+b-1
>   siblings with the same element name before it in the document tree,
>   for a given positive or zero value for n, and has a parent element.

```css
    .test:nth-of-type(2) a, .test:nth-of-type(4) a{
       display:none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="test">
   <a href="#" class="demo">Demo1</a>
</div>
<div class="test">
   <a href="#" class="demo">Demo2</a>
</div>
<div class="test">
   <a href="#" class="demo">Demo3</a>
</div>
<div class="test">
   <a href="#" class="demo">Demo4</a>
</div>
```

Or

[`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) with the `odd` switch if you want a repeating pattern of hiding elements

> The `:nth-child(an+b)` CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has
>   an+b-1 siblings before it in the document tree, for a given positive
>   or zero value for n, and has a parent element.

```css
  .test:nth-child(even) a {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <a href="#" class="demo">Demo1</a>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <a href="#" class="demo">Demo2</a>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <a href="#" class="demo">Demo3</a>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <a href="#" class="demo">Demo4</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I want to hide only the Demo2 & Demo4 links. Because each div has other contents

Answer (score 0):

Use `nth-child` to select a `div` and then change its `a` to `hidden` http://jsfiddle.net/8gh7js6a/

```
.test:nth-child(2) a {
visibility:hidden;
}
.test:nth-child(4) a {
visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: where have you linked your fiddle to?